# Swift - passing specific tabcontroller size to another view controller?

Tags: swift, xcode, view

I create a UITabController programmatically, which obviously have a TabBar, which in turn contains two TabBar items. I also created an instance for a custom NavigationBar inside this class.

By default TabBar item 1 gets displayed, TabBar item 1 is a UIViewController class, which have an instance created inside it for a custom UICollectionView. When TabBar item 1 gets displayed inside the UITabBarController it stretches to cover all the screen. Thus, parts of it falls behind the custom NavigationBar inside the UITabController class as well as its TabBar.

What I would like to achieve is to have the custom UICollectionView, which I created an instance from inside the TabBar item 1 to get displayed inside the UITabBarController class to the bottom to the custom NavigationBar as well as the top of the TabBar.

Thus, I am wondering what is the best way to achieve this? Is it possible to pass to the UIViewController, which contains the custom UICollectionView instance the size of the safe area of the UITabBarController. So that when it gets displayed inside the UITabBarController, it will be bounded to the bottom of the NavigationBar as well as to the top of the TabBar?

Regards, 
Shadi

Answer (score 0):

I think you should achieve this by using the `additionalSafeAreaInsets` property of UIViewController. You should set correct edge values to this.